# How to export XML from Naviswork to Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-navisworks

I following this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/load-xml-navisworks-saved-viewpoints-forge-viewer-cameras)
for import and work with viewpoint from Naviswork to Forge Viewer.

Do you know any solution or API on Naviswork to export this viewpoint data and saved it on my Database. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a Navisworks API question, instead of Forge. Navisworks API does not provide a direct method to export to saved viewpoints like UI does. I happened to answer a similar question in the past. just copied here for your reference:

There is not a direct API, but with SavedViewpoint API, you could dump the data from the objects, and write to the XML yourself.
http://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2012/06/navisworks-net-api-2013-new-feature-saved-viewpoint.html

It might be possible not all properties in the standard xml have corresponding object with API, such as terminal_velocity, however it would not impact your workflow, as most properties (especially camera related) are available with API.

About data of redline, activate each saved viewpoint one by one (by DocumentSavedViewpoints.CurrentSavedViewpoint) , call Document.ActiveView.GetRedLines(). It can return all info of the annotations: line, eclipse, text etc in Json format.

About data of clip planes, you could use Document.ActiveView.GetClippingPlanes(). Similarly, in Json format.

Hope it helps.